# Linked list C++

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have to ADD a node to the end of a Linked LIST, it's not throwing any errors so far, but apparently it's not working too. I've looked into others answers, but couldn't see what's wrong with mine.
I think that the problem might be with getNext() and NULLs.
ps: I'm using HPP

Here's the method :

```
// ADD a node to the end of the Linked list
void add(const T& dado)
{
    Elemento < T > *novo = new Elemento<T>(dado, NULL);
    if (novo == NULL)
    {
        throw 2;
    }
    if (head->getNext() != NULL)
    {
        Elemento < T > *auxi = new Elemento<T>(dado, head->getNext());
        int i;
        for (i = 0; auxi->getNext() == NULL; i++)
        {
            auxi->setNext(auxi->getNext());
            if (auxi->getNext()() == NULL)
            {
                size++;
                auxi->setNext(novo);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size++;
        head->setNext(novo);
    }
}
```

My elemento class is as follow:

```
#ifndef ELEMENTO_HPP
#define ELEMENTO_HPP

template<typename T>
class Elemento {
 private:
    T *info;
    Elemento<T>* _next;

 public:
    Elemento(const T& info, Elemento<T>* next) : info(new T(info)), _next(next) {}

    ~Elemento() {
        delete info;
    }

    Elemento<T>* getNext() const     {
        return _next;
    }

    T getInfo() const {
        return *info;
    }

    void setNext(Elemento<T>* next) {
        _next = next;
    }
};

#endif
```

You can see the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/7yJfsK8j
(method names in Portuguese, but there are comments to explain).

Comment: Have you step-through debugged your code?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: is it September yet?

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong in several ways. **Try something simpler.** Write a function that prints the values in the list, but stops when it reaches the specified one.

Comment: Odds of you wanting to `new` two links for a single add approach zero. I'd rethink that if I were you. I don't have code for the constructor, but odds of you wanting to delete info in the destructor also approach 0. And if you do need to delete info, I'd think that over as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for-loop:

```
Elemento<T> *ptr;

//Will iterate until ptr-> getNext() is null (this means ptr is not null).
for(ptr = head; ptr -> getNext() != NULL; ptr = ptr -> getNext())
{
   //Does nothing.
};
ptr -> setNext(novo);

size++;
```

Hope it works!

Comment: `size` is probably meant to store the size of the list.

Comment: Oh okay - added it in to my answer :-)

Comment: I'd do another edit to do two things: 1. Your target audience is a rookie. Be explicit as heck and write the termination condition in full form: `ptr -> getNext() == NULL`. 2. For the same reason, expand the the loop braces onto  their own lines and put a big, fat `//Does nothing` comment in between them to hammer the point home.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the advice! I'll edit my answer right now. :-)

Comment: And you caught my mistake too. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Thanks, again!